# Excel get multiple sub-strings from a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have got an Excel file with a column named `Comments` in a sheet called `Resources` (accessible as `Resources[@Comments]`), the data looks something similar to,

```
+=============================================+
| Comments                                    |
+=============================================+
| [7/2] Level changed from 10 to 9            |
| [14/2] Alignment changed from ABC to XYZ    |
| [21/2] Location changed from US to UK       |
| [28/2] Chapter changed from [blank] to ABCD |
+---------------------------------------------+
| [14/2] Level changed from 5 to 4            |
| [21/2] Location changed from US to UK       |
| [21/2] Chapter changed from JKLM to ABCD    |
+---------------------------------------------+
| [28/2] Chapter changed from EFGH to MNOP    |
+---------------------------------------------+
| [21/2] Location changed from IN to JP       |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

The output I'm looking for should look something like (essentially extracting text between `Chapter changed from <`**SOURCE**`> to <`**DESTINATION**`>`),

```
+=============================================+==============+==============+
| Comments                                    | Old Chapter  | New Chapter  |
+=============================================+==============+==============+
| [7/2] Level changed from 10 to 9            | [blank]      | ABCD         |
| [14/2] Alignment changed from ABC to XYZ    |              |              |
| [21/2] Location changed from US to UK       |              |              |
| [28/2] Chapter changed from [blank] to ABCD |              |              |
+---------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+
| [14/2] Level changed from 5 to 4            |              |              |
| [21/2] Location changed from US to UK       |              |              |
| [21/2] Chapter changed from JKLM to ABCD    |              |              |
+---------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+
| [28/2] Chapter changed from EFGH to MNOP    | EFGH         | MNOP         |
+---------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+
| [21/2] Location changed from IN to JP       |              |              |
+---------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Notes:

- Cell might not have any "Chapter changed" text in which case no processing is required.
- "Chapter changed" text is always the last line.
- Only want to track the change if it was today (e.g. [28/2] `=TEXT(today(), "dd/m"`)
- I think Excel wraps text within `""` (double quotes).

I am happy with either Excel formula or VBA script. Already tried stuff like KuTools, `=MID(Resources[@Comments],SEARCH("Chapter changed from",Resources[@Comments])+20,SEARCH("to", Resources[@Comments]) - SEARCH("Chapter changed from",Resources[@Comments])-21)`.

To check the date part I am using, `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("["&TEXT(TODAY(), "dd/m")&"] Chapter changed", Resources[@Comments])), "Yes", "")`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple actually...

1. Spilt the cell contents using `vbnewline` or `Chr(10)`
2. Split on "["
3. Split on "]"
4. Check Date
5. Split on "from"
6. Split on "to"

**Code**: Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim cellValue As String
    Dim tmpAr As Variant
    Dim Dt As String, lastLine As String
    Dim OLDc  As String, NEWc As String
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Set the range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2")

    '~~> Split on Linefeed. It could be Chr(13) as well
    tmpAr = Split(rng.Value, Chr(10))

    '~~> Get the last line
    lastLine = tmpAr(UBound(tmpAr))

    '~~> Get the date part
    Dt = Split(lastLine, "[")(1)
    Dt = Split(Dt, "]")(0)

    '~~> Check if it is same as today
    If Format(Date, "D/M") = Dt Then
        lastLine = Split(lastLine, "from")(1)
        OLDc = Trim(Split(lastLine, "to")(0))
        NEWc = Trim(Split(lastLine, "to")(1))

        rng.Offset(, 1).Value = OLDc
        rng.Offset(, 2).Value = NEWc
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Replace()` method of `Range` object:

```
Sub DoThat()
    Dim cell As Range
    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2).Value = .Value
        For Each cell In .Offset(, 1).Cells
            If InStr(cell.Value2, Format(Date, "D/M")) > 0 Then
                cell.Replace "*from ", ""
                cell.Replace " to *", ""                
                cell.Offset(, 1).Replace "*to ", ""
            Else
                cell.Resize(, 2).ClearContents
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Would the `cell.Replace()` method work considering there can be multiple instances `"from "` and `"to " in a given cell? e.g. Level changed from 10 to 9.